# Error in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;
set define off;
exec dbms_output.enable(20000);
set pagesize 2000;

declare
Test_Date1 Date;
test_date2 DATE;
Day_Of_Week Varchar2(3);
Years_Ahead Number := 0;
New_Var Number := 0;
New_Var1 Number := 0;
New_Var2 Number := 0;
Dd1 Number := 0;
Dd2 Number := 0;
Mm1 Number := 0;
mm2 Number := 0;

Begin
    test_date1 := TO_DATE('01/12/2017 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    test_date2 := To_Date('01/12/2017 08:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    dd1 :=(test_date1,'dd');
    dd2 :=(test_date2,'dd');
    mm1 :=(test_date1,'mm');
    mm2 :=(Test_Date2,'mm');
    For Years_Ahead In Dd1..Dd2 Loop
            Select Count(User_Id) Into New_Var From Lg_Usage_Statistics Where Timestamp Between Test_Date1 And Test_Date1;
            Select Count(User_Id) Into New_Var1 From Lg_Usage_Statistics Where Timestamp Between To_Date('01/12/2017 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') And To_Date('02/12/2017 23:59:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
            Select COUNT(User_Id) into New_Var2 From Lg_Usage_Statistics Where Timestamp Between To_Date('01/12/2017 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') And To_Date('02/12/2017 23:59:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); 
End Loop;
END;
/
```

I am trying to get the count of users into variable but getting these errors

```
Error:
Error starting at line 6 in command:
declare
Test_Date1 Date;
test_date2 DATE;
Day_Of_Week Varchar2(3);
Years_Ahead Number := 0;
New_Var Number := 0;
New_Var1 Number := 0;
New_Var2 Number := 0;
Dd1 Number := 0;
Dd2 Number := 0;
Mm1 Number := 0;
mm2 Number := 0;

Begin
    test_date1 := TO_DATE('01/12/2017 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    test_date2 := To_Date('01/12/2017 08:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    dd1 :=(test_date1,'dd');
    dd2 :=(test_date2,'dd');
    mm1 :=(test_date1,'mm');
    mm2 :=(Test_Date2,'mm');
    For Years_Ahead In Dd1..Dd2 Loop
        Select Count(User_Id) Into New_Var From Lg_Usage_Statistics Where Timestamp Between Test_Date1 And Test_Date1;
        Select Count(User_Id) Into New_Var1 From Lg_Usage_Statistics Where Timestamp Between To_Date('01/12/2017 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') And To_Date('02/12/2017 23:59:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
        Select COUNT(User_Id) into New_Var2 From Lg_Usage_Statistics Where Timestamp Between To_Date('01/12/2017 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') And To_Date('02/12/2017 23:59:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); 
    End Loop;
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 17, column 8:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 17, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 18, column 8:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 18, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 19, column 8:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 19, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 20, column 8:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 20, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Showing the code is excellent, and showing the full error message is even better. You still need to explain what the code is expected to do. As it is, people can (and already have) point out the error, but they can't tell you how to fix it, since it is not clear what the code was supposed to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dd1 :=(test_date1,'dd');
 dd2 :=(test_date2,'dd');
 mm1 :=(test_date1,'mm');
 mm2 :=(Test_Date2,'mm');
```

What do you want to accomplish here? This isn't valid plsql.

I'm guessing you want to use one of following functions:

```
TO_CHAR(test_date1, 'dd');
TRUNC(test_date1, 'dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from non-sense assignments like `dd1 :=(test_date1,'dd')` and so on .. to `numeric` variables at lines `17` through `20`.

the variables `dd1`, `dd2`, `mm1` and `mm2` are defined as number, so you may apply first `to_char`, and then `to_number` conversion to get the valid values for these variables.

```
dd1 :=to_number(to_char(test_date1,'dd'));
dd2 :=to_number(to_char(test_date2,'dd'));
mm1 :=to_number(to_char(test_date1,'mm'));
mm2 :=to_number(to_char(Test_Date2,'mm'));
```

Comment: Why `to_number(to_char(..., 'dd'))` and not `extract( day from ... )`? And same for month?